# TFS : Checkin code. Pending Changes for ever

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using VS 2013 with TFS. Whenever I try to check in my code ( changes only from current solution), Team Explorer - Pending Changes tab opens up and Pending Changes loads for ever. There were days when I waited almost for 4 hours. I restarted my computer several times but problem still happens. Did anyone faced this issue.

[image: Pending Changes]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In order to narrow down the issue, please check the items below:

1. Check on another client machine to see the issue is from client side or server side.
2. Make sure your VS and TFS has the latest edition of the version.
3. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.`
4. Go to TFS AT machine, and check event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is anything helpful.